# iOS Swift: Application name is pulled from project settings and not from Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, application-name

The title pretty much explains everything. I cant get my application name localized because it is pulled from the project settings' info tab and not from the Info.plist files.

How can I achieve, that the names in the localized info.plist files will be used, and not the one in the project settings?

Comment: have you written CFBundleDisplayName in info.plist and app name according to localization.

Comment: yeah I did! but it doesnt matter what I put into the plist files, the name is taken from the project settings :/

Comment: actually i also don't know much .have u tried any tutorial?

Comment: this is the link for tutorial that may help you for solving problem. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: I found this tutorial before, but it does not help...

Comment: ok let me try will tell u if it work.

Comment: ok, but I think its a configuration problem. I just need to tell xcode to use the plist files, cant be that hard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65668/discussion-between-johny-kumar-and-michael).

Comment: the key "Application has localized display name" has no effect either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I was very confused with the fact, that you can localize the Info.plist in your project. In fact you should never do that!

In the end I just needed to create a new strings-file (InfoPlist.strings). I localized this one and added:

"CFBundleDisplayName" = "NameInAccordingLanguage"

pretty simple in the end, but I got stuck trying to localize the Info.plist